# Any compact subset $K$ of a CW-complex $X$ meets finitely many cells.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, cw-complexes

> Any compact subset $K$ of a CW-complex $X$ meets finitely many cells.

The proof of the above result in the lecture note I am following argues along the following lines $:$

**Proof** $:$ For each cell $e_{\alpha}$ meeting $K,$ pick a point $k_{\alpha} \in K \cap e_{\alpha}.$ Let $S = \{k_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I},$ where $I$ is an indexing set consisting of all those $\alpha$ for which $K \cap e_{\alpha} \neq \varnothing.$ Let $X^{(n)}$ denote the $n$-skeleton of $X.$ Then clearly $S \cap X^{(0)}$ is closed in $X^{(0)}$ since $X^{(0)}$ is a discrete set. Assuming that $S \cap X^{n-1}$ is closed in $X^{(n-1)}.$ Now $S \cap X^{(n)}$ is the union of $S \cap X^{(n-1)}$ and the points $k_{\alpha}$ lying in the interior of the $n$-cells. **So $S \cap X^{(n)}$ is also closed in $X^{(n)}$ as both these sets are closed in** $X^{(n)}.$ Hence by induction $S$ is closed in $X^{(n)}.$ So $S$ is closed in $X,$ since $X$ is endowed with the weak topology.

By similar argument we can in fact show that any subset of $S$ is also closed in $X.$ Thus $S$ is discrete and $S$ being a closed subset of $K$ it follows that $S$ is compact. So $S$ has to be finite as it is both compact and discrete.

This completes the proof.

In the above proof I don't understand the bold faced sentence. Would anybody please help me understanding it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result is false as stated.  Consider the usual cell structure on $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ with one cell of each dimension and attaching map the usual 2-to-1 map $\partial e_n=S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$.  Let $K$ be the $0$-skeleton and this meets every $e_n$ by induction.  What is true is that it meets finitely many cells in their interior.

Comment: @user10354138 I think the $$e^{n}_{\alpha}$$'s are supposed to mean the image of the interior of an $$n$$-disk via the characteristic map.

Comment: @user10354138 Usually the word "cell" denotes an open cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X^{n-1} \cap S$ is closed in $X^{n-1}$ by inductive hypothesis, hence it is closed in $X^{n}$, since for any characteristic map of an $n$-cell, $\Phi$, $\Phi^{-1}(X^{n-1} \cap S) = \phi^{-1}(X^{n-1} \cap S)$ where $\phi = \Phi \restriction \partial D^n$ is the attaching map $\phi : \partial D^n \rightarrow X^{n-1}$. Since $\phi$ is continuous $\phi^{-1}(X^{n-1} \cap S)$ is a closed subset of $\partial D^n$ and thus a closed subset of $D^n$. Now the other set, namely the set of points $k_{\alpha}$ contained in $e^n_{\alpha} \cap S$ (i.e. exactly one $k_{\alpha}$ for every $e^n_{\alpha} \cap S \neq \emptyset$) has empty preimage by any characteristic map of a cell of dimension $< n$ or cell of dimension $n$ with index not equal to $\alpha$, and singleton preimage by any characteristic map of a cell of dimension $n$ with index $\alpha$, and is thus closed in $X^n$. The union of both these sets is thus closed in $X^n$.

Comment: I think that since $\Phi^{-1} (X^{n-1} \cap S) \subseteq D^{n-1} \subseteq S^{n-1} = \partial D^{n}$ we have $\Phi^{-1} (X^{n-1} \cap S) = \phi^{-1} (X^{n-1} \cap S).$ Right? But then what you have shown is that  $\Phi^{-1} (X^{n-1} \cap S)$ is closed in $D^n.$ Does it imply that $X^{n-1} \cap S$ is closed in $X^{n}\ $?

Comment: Well $\Phi : D^n \rightarrow X$, so we don't have $\Phi^{-1}(X^{n-1} \cap S) \subset D^{n-1}$, but we do have $\Phi^{-1}(X^{n-1} \cap S) \subset \partial D^{n} = S^{n-1}$, because $\Phi( int (D^{n})) \cap X^{n-1} = \emptyset$

Comment: $\Phi (\text {int} (D^n))$ is homeomorphic to an open $n$-cell. Right? But $X^{n-1}$ only intersects the boundary of each $n$-cell. Do you mean that?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Yes, once we know that the preimage of $X^{n-1} \cap S$ by any characteristic map of an $n$-cell is closed *and* that the preimage of $X^{n-1} \cap S$ by any characteristic map of a $k$-cell for $k < n$ is closed, then we indeed have that $X^{n-1} \cap S$ is closed in $X^n$, because by definition of weak topology, a subset of $X^n$ is closed iff the preimage of all characteristic maps of cells of $X^n$ on the subset are closed.

Comment: Yes, $\Phi(int(D^n))$ is homeomorphic to an open $n$-cell, $X^{n-1} \cap \Phi(int(D^n))$ is empty precisely because as you say, $X^{n-1}$ only intersects $\overline{e_{\alpha}^n}$ , and does not intersect $e_{\alpha}^n$.

Comment: In Hatcher the definition of weak topology seems different to me. He says that a subset $A$ of a CW complex $X$ is open (or closed) iff $A \cap X^n$ is open (or closed) in $X^n$ for any $n.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123980/discussion-between-porridgemathematics-and-phi-beta-kappa).

Comment: Here you have proved that the inverse image of $S \cap X^{n-1}$ under the characteristic map of the $n$-cell is closed in $D^n_{\alpha}.$ What about the inverse image of $S \cap X^{n-1}$ under the characteristic map of $m$ cells for $m \neq n$ in $D^m\ $?

Comment: Got it now. If $m \gt n$ and if $\Phi_{\alpha}$ be the characteristic map of $\alpha$-th $m$-cell then we have $$\Phi_{\alpha}^{-1} (S \cap X^{n-1}) = \phi_{\alpha}^{-1} (S \cap X^{n-1})$$ as $X^{n-1} \cap e_{\alpha}^m \subseteq X^{m-1} \cap e_{\alpha}^m = \varnothing.$ Similarly if $k \lt n$ then we have $$\Phi_{\beta}^{-1} (S \cap X^{n-1}) = \phi_{\beta}^{-1} (S \cap X^{k-1})$$ where $\Phi_{\beta}$ is the characteristic map of the $\beta$-th $k$-th cell. Many many thanks for your kind help. At last accepted your answer.

Comment: Actually it shows that $S \cap X^{n-1}$ is in fact open in $X$ with respect to the weak topology.